# Dictionary not subscriptable

Tags: python

I am new to python and machine learning. I want to plot a Zipf distribution graph for a text file. But my code gives some error.

Following is my python code

```
import re
#Get our corpus of medical words
frequency = {}
list(frequency)
open_file = open("abp.csv", 'r')
file_to_string = open_file.read()
words = re.findall(r'(\b[A-Za-z][a-z]{2,9}\b)', file_to_string)

#build dict of words based on frequency
for word in words:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1


#limit words to 1000
n = 1000
frequency = {key:value for key,value in frequency.items()[0:n]}
#convert value of frequency to numpy array
s = frequency.values()
s = np.array(s)

#Calculate zipf and plot the data
a = 2. #  distribution parameter
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s[s<50], 50, normed=True)
x = np.arange(1., 50.)
y = x**(-a) / special.zetac(a)
plt.plot(x, y/max(y), linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

and above code gives the following error.

```
 File "<ipython-input-100-e83a349c3bee>", line 2, in <module>
    frequency = {key:value for key,value in frequency.items()[0:n]}

TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `frequency.items()` is not a list but a generator instead, thus you cannot subscript it with the `[]` as the error message says.

You have two options

1. Transform the generator to a list by calling the `list` constructor `list(frequency.items())` before slicing.
2. To use the [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function from the `itertools` module that performs a slicing in an iterable `islice(frequency.items(), 0, n)`

Comment: After using the function it gives error for below:                                                         count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(s[s<50], 50, normed=True)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict_values' and 'int'

Comment: @AnamikaChavan that's another problem that should be another question. Keep questions self-contained only showing one issue at a time, and as an example that can be executed which is not the case now since I don't have the `abp.csv` file.